# Unknown C++ Error, {} are highlighted after if statement

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

Using Sublime (Am on my macbook instead of my main PC) and helping my sister out with her programming assignment.

I'm not a massive C++ expert and have learnt a lot from helping her out, but I'm still seemingly getting stumped by the basics.

The code below is a function I have written which runs a game that has been written inside a separate class which I don't have access to, I've only got a limited number of methods to use and can use as many times as I like.

The game is one of those 3x3 tile boards with the numbers 1-8 and a space which you move around to re arrange the board trying to get the numbers in order (see picture) [Sliding puzzle, like this but with numbers instead of the smiley face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG7JQ.jpg), The code calls the update function based on input and prints the board afterwards.

I didn't have any issues until I added in the final if statement at the end of the method. Now the final two '{'s are highlighted pink and the preceeding methods have lost their green name...

I'm stumped, help?

```
void beginGamePlay () {
    gameInPlay = true;
    char gameMenuChoice = '';
    // While gameInPlay is True, game will loop
    while (gameInPlay) {
        //Print new inGame menu
        printInGameMenu();

        while (putchar (tolower(gameMenuChoice) != 'm') {
            if (putchar (tolower(gameMenuChoice)) != 'u' || 'd' || 'l' || 'r'){
                cout << "Invalid Input, Try again:";
                printInGameMenu();
            } else {
                puzzle.updateBoard(gameMenuChoice);
                puzzle.printBoard();
                break;
            }
        }
        // Check if the game ends
        if (puzzle.gameOver()) {
            gameInPlay = false;
            cout << "You WIN!";
        }

    }

}
```

[Full Colour Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGss2.png)

Comment: second `while` statement is missing a `)` before `{`. currently it's `...gameMenuChoice) != 'm') {` and it should be `gameMenuChoice) != 'm') ) {`

Comment: Why are you repeatedly printing `gameMenuChoice` without changing it?

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to your formating and display color question ...

```
if (putchar (tolower(gameMenuChoice)) != 'u' || 'd' || 'l' || 'r')
```

is not going to work the way you think. You need to use:

```
char ch = putchar(tolower(gameMenuChoice));
if ( ch == 'u' ||
     ch == 'd' ||
     ch == 'l' ||
     ch == 'r' ) { ... }
```